# Laravel Eloquent query builder - date filtering is not working

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a method where I need to filter by date and only show results that has "end_date" column set to after parameter "$start".

Table "order" contains a DATE column "end_date", say if parameter $start is 2017-05-30, it should not return "orders" unless the "end_date" of the record in order table is after 2017-05-30.

The query below should be fine but it's returning all order records. I tried with Carbon parse and without, neither worked. Can anyone tell me where I've done wrong?

Thanks heaps!

```
public function returnordersbydate($user,$start,$end){

 return Order::where('user_id','=',$user->id)

->whereDate('end_date','>=',Carbon::parse($start)->toDateString())

->has('orderdaytimes')

->whereHas('orderdaytimes',function($q) use($start,$end){

    $q -> where('date','>=',$start)->where('date','<=',$end);

  })->orderBy('id')->get();


}
```

Comment: `$q -> where('date','>=',$start)->where('date','<=',$end);`
why they are `where` not `whereDate` ?

Comment: i changed to whereDate, nothing changed.. this part shouldn't have anything to do with the issue I'm having since the "end_date" field is in Orders table.

Comment: are you sure formats of dates are correct ? I had similar issue try to get a special date and try wheredate with `=` instead of `>=` and see if you recieve it

Comment: doesn't seem to apply the filter at all evenif i change to "="..ahh..